# How to create a loop using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute the below code by creating a simple loop using jQuery, I can also change the classes if needed.

I want to shrink the code as much as possible.

```
     $( ".btn1" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn1" );
     });
     $( ".btn2" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn2" );
     });
     $( ".btn3" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn3" );
     });
     $( ".btn4" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn4" );
     });
     $( ".btn5" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn5" );
     });
     $( ".btn6" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn6" );
     });
     $( ".btn7" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn7" );
     });
     $( ".btn8" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn8" );
     });
     $( ".btn9" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn9" );
     });
     $( ".btn10" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn10" );
     });
     $( ".btn11" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn11" );
     });
     $( ".btn12" ).click(function() {
     $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn12" );
     });
```

Comment: Another way of tackling this is to give each item two identifiers - `.btn` for all of them, and then `#btn1` (with a number) for each one. You can then just attach a click handler to `$('.btn')` and then read the id from inside the handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
  $( ".btn" + i ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "act-btn" + i );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your logic, And number of elements is `dynamic` or `static`. Anyway using simple loop like below may solve your problem.

```js
    for(let i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
        $(`.btn${i}`).click(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass(`act-btn${i}`);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to make a general class like `.button` and add it to every button, thun also make a general action class `.btn-action`, it would look somthing like this:

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('btn-action');
})
```

Comment: @UjjawalPoonia: this will work, and is a more efficient way to use jQuery. You would need to modify your HTML. Presently your code appears to be specifying unique identifiers in class names, but they should really be IDs.